# Initialize ng-app after document is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with AngularJS.

One of the (technical) requirements is to fetch the "ng enabled" HTML content from the server, in response to a click event, and inject it into a `<div ng-app>` via JavaScript.

The problem is that the newly injected HTML is not wired, as Angular goes through the *compile* and *link* phases only when the page is loaded the first time.

Is there a way to trigger them manually?
Am I approaching this problem in the wrong way? Is there a more idiomatic way to accomplish what I described?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to inject dynamic content into the view in AngularJS. One of the way to inject dynamic content is to use `ng-include` directive. It can take an endpoint from where to get view.
You can combine it with `ng-if` to achieve load view on click. For example:

```
<span ng-if="clicked">
   <div ng-include='pathToTheHtml'></div>
</span>
```

The `clicked` variable would be false first, on clicking on the button set it to true, this would trigger `ng-include` to get the content and inject it into html.

If you want finer control then you need to use the $compile service. The html that needs to be injected into the DOM needs to be compiled and linked to the scope using $compile service. This can be done in a directive.

element.append(`$compile(htmlFragment)(scope)`)

Answer (score 1):

[angular.bootstrap(element, [modules], [config]);](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)